# Update Query not Triggering After Update Event (MS Access)

Tags: ms-access

I saw post with similar question but seems it could not answer mine, I apologize upfront if this is a duplicated post, as I think my problem is a bit different from what was being asked in another previous post.

I have created a continuous form where there are 2 textbox, which will do calculation with each other when either one of them are being changed.

One is a "Mark-up" textbox with code of `Me.Mark_Up = (Me.Unit_Selling_Price / Me.Cost_Unit_Price) - 1`
Another textbox is a "Unit Selling Price" textbox with code of `Me.Unit_Selling_Price = (Me.EUR_Cost_Unit_Price) * (1 + Me.Mark_Up)`. Each code was being put under as the After Update event, triggering the calculation if the other textbox has been changed.

Then I added a "Round-up" button which will execute the update query which then will roundup the number in the "Unit Selling Price" textbox. I tried 2 ways to update the "Mark-up" textbox but neither way works:

1. Insert code into update query to update the mark-up textbox as well but turns out all calculation done are inaccurate (examples as below):

   [image]
2. Insert code of `Me.Mark_Up = (Me.Unit_Selling_Price / Me.Cost_Unit_Price) - 1` after pressing the "Round-up" button and executing the update query, but "Mark-up" textbox did not update accordingly.

How should I code this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that when you use VBA code to update a control (or a query), then the event stubs (such as after update) do NOT fire.

So, if you going to use code to update the data?

You need to code in the use of the after update code.

There are several ways to do this, but one tip would be to make sure that the after update code is a "stand alone" type of code routine. That way, you can use the SAME code in one place for both operations. (you really don't want to have to maintain two copies of that calculation code - since it THEN becomes rather easy to have those two routines use differnt rounding or slightly different code - thus resulting in DIFFERENT results for what should be the same thing.

So for the several text boxes, and the after update code? You could say set things up this way:

```
Me.Mark_Up = MyMarkUpCalc(Me.Unit_Selling_Price, Me.Cost_Unit_Price)
```

And then in the form have this:

Public Function MymarkUpCalc(cSell as currency, cCost as currency) as currency
MymarkUpCalc = (cSell / cCost) - 1
End Function

So now you have a COMMON routine.

Now, in your code that does the "round"

I would suggest this code:

Sub MyRound
if me.dirty = true then me.dirty = false 'save any pending writes

```
  dim rst     as DAO.ReocrdSet
  set rst = me.RecordSetClone

  rst.moveFirst
  do While rst.EOF = false
     rst.Edit
     rst!SomeRoundField = some new value
     rst!Unit_Selling_Price = MyMarkUpCalc(rst!Unit_Selling_Price, rst!Unit_CostPrice
     rst.Update
     rst.MoveNext
  loop
```

So, in place of say a update query (sql), I think a loop + code will work somewhat better, and thus you now have a common set of calculation routines. Even if the routine is wrong, it will be constant wrong!

So now both your after update events, and your round up processing routine(s) will both use the SAME calculation code.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell your issue, as we don't have your secret update code.

Your results seem a bit off, so something is wrong. The correct results (last column) should be:

```vb
c              c * (1 + m)    -Int(-c * (1 + m))
  296.53        505.049896      506 
 2225.69       3790.795208     3791 
 7074.41      12049.135112    12050 
 4659.79       7936.554328     7937
```

For extended rounding methods, study my project [VBA.Round](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Round).